# Cannot copy a directory with Ansible copy module

Tags: ansible

I been trying to copy a directory (in Linux) to a remote Windows node. I can copy single files without any issue. But when I been trying to copy a directory getting the following error.

Environment: Windows 7

Command: ansible --verbose Windows -m copy -a "src=~/Releases dest=C:\Ansible"

Error:

```
10.8.0.4 | FAILED => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 561, in _executor
    exec_rc = self._executor_internal(host, new_stdin)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 666, in _executor_internal
    return self._executor_internal_inner(host, self.module_name, self.module_args, inject, port, complex_args=complex_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 884, in _executor_internal_inner
    result = handler.run(conn, tmp, module_name, module_args, inject, complex_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/action_plugins/copy.py", line 252, in run
    module_return = self.runner._execute_module(conn, tmp_path, 'copy', module_args_tmp, inject=inject, complex_args=complex_args, delete_remote_tmp=delete_remote_tmp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 483, in _execute_module
    argsfile = self._transfer_str(conn, tmp, 'arguments', utils.jsonify(utils.parse_kv(args)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/utils/__init__.py", line 690, in parse_kv
    vargs = split_args(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/module_utils/splitter.py", line 182, in split_args
    raise Exception("error while splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes")
Exception: error while splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible currently has a fairly [limited set of modules for Windows](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_windows_modules.html), and I don't believe that the copy module is supported for Windows systems.  Windows versions of the copy, file, and template modules were [recently accepted](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/384) into the ansible-modules-core project on github.  It looks like they depend on a separate [pull request into ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/9611) itself, and it's apparently slated to be available in ansible 1.9.  The modules will be named win_copy, win_file, and win_template when they become available.

Comment: Another way I was thinking, we can .zip the folder and copy the .zip file into the remote windows node, then easily unzip it from a ps script.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, totally agree with Bruce.

I have found this VERY useful module which is copy.ps1

https://gist.github.com/tkinz27/fd92ba9af0e0309614ee

And then things got working :-)

Important: You gotta upgrade your Windows (7) Powershell to Version 4.0

And yes it's really good to see new windows functionalists for Ansible.